# format date in javascript using d3.js tool

Tags: javascript, d3.js, date-format

If I have a file formatted in this way:

```
date    close
11-30-1-May-12  582.13
10-30-1-Apr-12  382.13
9-30-1-Mar-12   482.13
```

how i can change this line of code

```
d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse
```

In terms which i can catch also minutes and hour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `d3.time.format('%H-%M-%e-%b-%y').parse`